# Convert all array elments' ISODates to their equivalent JSON document in mongo 3.4 (not 3.6)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose that my profile collections look like this :

```
{
_id : ObjectId("59cb823013e825455b1c1a04"),
positions : 
[
    {
        "uid" : 5,
        "startDate" : ISODate("2016-11-30T23:00:00.000Z")
    },
    {
        "uid" : 6,
        "startDate" : ISODate("2011-10-31T23:00:00.000Z")
    }
]
}
```

I want to convert all startDate fields in positions to this format :

```
{
year : 2012,
month : 11,
day : 10
}
```

I tried to run this query :

```
db.profile.find({})
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.positions.forEach(function (position) {
        var year = { $year: position.startDate };
        var month = { $month: position.startDate };
        var day = { $day: position.startDate };
        position.startDate = {
            year : year,
            month : month;
            day : day;
            };
    });
    db.profile.save(doc);
  });
```

but I'm getting this error :
**Error: field names cannot start with $ [$year]**

Any help on having this work?

Comment: `$year` and other date operators you've used are aggregation operators. Simply use `position.startDate.getFullYear()`, `position.startDate.getMonth()` and `position.startDate.getDate()` respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get to solve this by using :

```
db.profile.find({})
  .forEach(function (doc) {
    doc.positions.forEach(function (position) {
        var year = position.startDate.getFullYear();
        var month = position.startDate.getMonth();
        var day = position.startDate.getDay();
        position.startDate = {
            year : year,
            month : month;
            day : day;
            };
    });
    db.profile.save(doc);
  });
```